# Whats the difference between "IsPresent=1" and "IsInstalled=1" in search criteria of IUpdateSearcher

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop-application, wmic

I was trying to retrieve Windows Update with WUA API of IUpdateSearcher interface's search method.

The search criteria I have passed as "IsInstalled=1 or IsPresent=1". Please find below is the sample code.

```
IUpdateSearcher* searcher;
ISearchResult* results;
/*
.
.
Code to initialize COM and get UpdateSearcher*/
.
.
*/

hRes = searcher->Search("IsInstalled=1 or IsPresent=1", &results);
```

I have gone through the definition of IsInstalled and IsPresent in MSDN (Copied for reference). Both talk about similar things.

```
IsPresent   
When set to 1, finds updates that are present on a computer.
"IsPresent=1" finds updates that are present on a destination computer. If the update
is valid for one or more products, the update is considered present if it is installed
for one or more of the products."IsPresent=0" finds updates that are not installed 
for any product on a destination   computer.

IsInstalled
Finds updates that are installed on the destination computer.
"IsInstalled=1" finds updates that are installed on the destination computer.
"IsInstalled=0" finds updates that are not installed on the destination computer.
```

Could someone please clarify what exactly they differ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better explanation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386103(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is the relevant text:

"Remarks

An update is considered present if it is installed for one or more products. For example, if an update applies to both Microsoft Office Word and to Microsoft Office Excel, the IsPresent property returns VARIANT_TRUE if the update is installed for one or both of the products.

If an update applies to only one product, the IsPresent and IsInstalled properties are equivalent. An update is considered installed if the update is installed for all the products to which it applies.

If IsPresent returns VARIANT_TRUE and IsInstalled returns VARIANT_FALSE, the update can be uninstalled for the product that installed it."